# IOS - How can I add a tab bar to navigation controller (Master Detail template)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I created my IOS 5 project using the "Master Detail" template in XCode4. This template give you a navigation controller. At some point I realized that I would like to add a tab bar to this application. So I'd like to keep the navigation controller but I'd like to add the tab bar. Can someone summarize how this can be done or perhaps direct me to a good resource to research how this is done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding a tab bar to a navigation controller may cause your application to be rejected from the app store. From the design guidelines:

> ```
> When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar 
> controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers. You never want to 
> push a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack of a navigation controller. Doing so 
> creates an unusual situation whereby the tab bar appears only while a specific view 
> controller is at the top of the navigation stack. Tab bars are designed to be persistent, 
> and so this transient approach can be confusing to users.
> ```

A navigation controller should be added to a tab bar instead.

Comment: I see. I would like the tab bar to be persistent. So what's the least painful way to convert to a tab bar application?