# Objective C Master Detail project with tab bar on detail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, xcode4.4

My project is setup so that a user will search for a particular item. This item has three  different groups of detail information.  What I wanted to do, is create a Master/Detail scenario and then on the Detail screen have a tab bar with three different views to match the three different groups of detail info.  However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work.  I searched and found this stackoverflow question:

[IOS - How can I add a tab bar to navigation controller (Master Detail template)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595416/ios-how-can-i-add-a-tab-bar-to-navigation-controller-master-detail-template)

Which seems to suggest that if I follow my plan, Apple will likely not accept my app because the tab bar should be persistent across the app.  This seems ridiculous to me.  There are plenty of scenarios where the tab bar shouldn't be on every view.  For instance, the first view in my app is a login screen.  I certainly don't want the tab bar there.  Is this something anyone else has encountered?  And if so, do you know of any tutorials that could help me get this working?

I work in xcode 4.4 and use the storyboard rather than the nib files.  Right now I'm able to get my master view to navigate to the detail view and I can see the tab bar on the detail view.  However, my views in the detail have table views with static cells and I can't see any of the information that is supposed to be in them.

Answer (score 0):

There are rules and there are guidelines.  Apple does not have a rule that if you have a tab bar, it must be present everywhere in your app.  They have guidelines which state that tab bars should be consistent across views.  Apple has rules like, don't use unpublished API calls.  Those rules will get your app rejected, and they are in the app store submission guidelines.  The user interface guidelines are really guidelines for how you should create your app, unless you have an overriding good reason to do otherwise.